# visual studio code crashed and then contiunes crashing when trying to open

Tags: visual-studio-code, crash

I was writing code when suddenly, studio code crashed.

[image]

I had 4/5 projects opened on different windows, but it never happened to me.

Now, when trying to open, it always throws that error, it doesn't even get to load anything.. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often you can solve problems like that with an re-installation of VS-Code. If it still not works maybe you installed some other programm/driver which messed something up?

You could try installing VS Codium to see if there is a general problem with your installation. If you have trouble with that you might need to analise more.

Before you trying to reinstall anything I would suggest a restart of your computer maybe that solves your problem.

Comment: Restarting my machine worked for me

Comment: In my case it happend when memory is full.
When i close browsers and programs - vscode stop crushing